# Set height and Width of Pop Window on button click which button is reside in that window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have open a aspx page as Pop Window.

In this aspx page I have two div one for Data and one for No data.

When There is no data I visible no data div. In which I have a images and simple message in it.

I have set my pop window height : 730px and width : 1050px

and I have set no data div height :600px and width : 850px.

Now When there is no data div is visible I want to set Pop Window height and width same as no data div.

So How can I set height and width of Pop up window at runtime.

I have use below code to visible no data div.

```
 dvData.Visible = false;
 dvNodata.Visible = false;
 lblMessage.Text = "";
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the following javascript function on the designer of your popup page and call it when you set the visibility of your no data DIV to true:

```
function resize_now(){
    window.moveTo(new_posx,new_posxy);
    window.resizeTo(newSizeX, newSizeY);
}
```

Hope this helps.